# how to show the json description respective id in ionic 3

Tags: html, json, typescript, ionic-framework

I have json a file like

```
[{
    "id": "1",
    "title": "Abba Father (1)",
    "description": "Abba Abba Father."
},
{
    "id": "2",
    "title": "Abba Father, Let me be (2)",
    "description": "Abba Father, Let me be (2) we are the clay."
},
{
    "id": "3",
    "title": "Abide with me (3)",
    "description": "Abide with me (3) we are the clay."
}]
```

I am able to show the description in next page when user clicked on the title list in home page. But in next page I have next and previous buttons, when user clicked on next button I need to show the next description. could any one guide me to do this task

I am using this project to implement this.

https://github.com/kristofferandreasen/simple-ionic-3-app

```
constructor(
    public navCtrl: NavController,
    private navParams: NavParams,
    // private itemApi: ItemApi
)
{
    this.item = this.navParams.data;
    console.log(this.item);
    console.log(this.item.id)
}


navigatePrivious($event, item)
{
    this.navCtrl.push(SingleSongPage, item);
}

navigateNext($event, item)
{
    this.navCtrl.push(SingleSongPage, item);
}
```

[image]

Comment: please give me any suggestions for json format. Am I have right json format for this task?

Comment: And for future questions: Screenshots and JSON/data is not as important as a minimal excerpt of the relevant code. That will increase speed and amount of answers enormous ;)  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On your `SingleSongPage` you get only one item passed via `NavParams` service.
So the only thing you have, to indicate what the next and the previous item is, is the current `item`.

You will get both items only from the `ItemApi` service now.
So uncomment and use it:

```typescript
ionViewDidLoad() {
    this.itemApi.getItems().then(data => {
        let currentIndex = data.indexOf(this.item);
        if (currentIndex > -1) {
            this.nextItem = data[currentIndex + 1];
            this.previousItem = data[currentIndex - 1];
        }
    });
}
```

And in your view, pass the `nextItem` and `previousItem` as parameter:

```html
<ion-button (click)="navigate($event, previousItem)">Previous Item</ion-button>
<ion-button (click)="navigate($event, nextItem)">Next Item</ion-button>
```

(your `navigateNext` and `navigatePrivious` functions became `navigate`).

Of course, I guess, it is not the best practise to load all items on every load of `SingleSongPage`. The `itemApi` service or any other service should hold/cache all (or an excerpt of all) items instead.
Or the API should provide something like `getNextSong(currentId: number): SongItem`.
But in case of this static json file or mockup data, it is okay.

Comment: loadDataSample()
  {
    let data : Observable<any>;
    data = this.http.get('assets/english.json');

    data.subscribe(result => {

      this.items = result;

    })

  }

Comment: I am using this code for fetching english.json data. What is the itemApi in this code?

Comment: if you need the content of english.json on multiple pages, your `loadDataSample()` should be placed within a service ("itemApi"). So you could bind to `itemApi.items` from everywhere.